# How to add a "&" sign if more than one error in the header function

Tags: php

My situation: 
I'm making a PHP contact form and I want my contact form to show the specific input textareas that are empty. 
For example, a person who uses my contact form had written a message and the subject line but not their email address and the `reCAPTCHA` is wrong. **I want to show the person who uses it why the email couldn't be sent by specifically telling them what went wrong**. I thought of using the `$_GET` method on the contact page. 
For example: http://example.com/contact?email=empty&recaptcha=incorrect

#### My problem:

When I was creating the contact form, I noticed that I will always have the `&` sign in the header function of php. I want the header function in my process page to not include the `&` sign if there is one incorrect thing. 
For example: http://example.com/contact?email=empty&

Comment: I'd do this typically in POST. Look in Google for "form validation PHP", there are many tutorials on how to do this in POST.

Comment: @elclanrs This is actually pretty common, using POST to process the form then use query strings to set the error message/status code when redirecting back to the form. I'm kinda filling in the blanks and guessing this is what the OP is doing, could be wrong. I just don't get why there's an extra `&` or why it's even an issue. Can you show your full code Mr. Alvin Tang?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Right, I misread the question. I don't get why the extra `&` either...

Comment: Would it affect my contact form if I had another & sign?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off building an array and then using [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http-build-query) to put it into a query string for you. This has the neat effect of also escaping the necessary characters.